# Java communication client/server

Tags: java, stream, client-server

This is in my client:

```
public static void logIn(String name, String pass) {
try {
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    out.print(name + "," + pass);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    System.out.println(in.readLine());

    in.close();
    s.close();
}
catch(UnknownHostException exp)
{
    exp.printStackTrace();

}
catch(java.io.IOException exp)
{
    exp.printStackTrace();
}   
}
```

and this I have in my server:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
 boolean clientExists=false;
 ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
 users.add(new User("jmeno","heslo"));
 ServerSocket ss;
 try {
    ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
    while(true) {
                clientExists=false;
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        String xmlpacket="";
                String pom;

                while ((pom = in.readLine())!=null){
                     xmlpacket+=pom;
                     xmlpacket+="\n";
                }

                for(User us: users)
                    {
                            if(us.isUserNameAndPasswordRight(login, passwd))
                            {
                                    out.print("user is connected");
                                    out.flush();
                                    clientExists=true;
                            }
                    }
                }
                if(clientExist != true)
              out.print("bad login");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        s.close();
}
catch(java.io.IOException exp)
{
    System.out.println("chyba u socketu!");
}
```

}

Is it posible to working like that? I can´t get this working because exception on client side when try reading from server the answer.

Edit:
This is stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at client.client.logIn(client.java:79)


    at client.GUI.GUI.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(GUI.java:379)
    at client.GUI.GUI.access$5(GUI.java:367)
    at client.GUI.GUI$5.actionPerformed(GUI.java:151)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please submit the exception plus stacktrace and highlight the offending method/line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did several things, so give all the code.

- Placed the buffered reader later, to possibly prevent blocking.
- Added encoding, so it does not use default OS encoding (client on different OS).
- Did println i.o. print.
- Autoflushing.
- Inportant: no PrintStream but PrintWriter.
- No loop on xmlpacket; that was code for later.

  ```
  public static void logIn(String name, String pass) {
  try {
      Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
      //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8");
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);
      out.println(name + "," + pass);
      out.flush();

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              s.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

      System.out.println(in.readLine());

      out.close();
      in.close();
      s.close();
  } catch (UnknownHostException exp) {
      exp.printStackTrace();

  } catch (java.io.IOException exp) {
      exp.printStackTrace();
  }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
  users.add(new User("jmeno", "heslo"));
  ServerSocket ss;
  try {
      ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
      while (true) {
          Socket s = ss.accept();
          System.out.println("Accept...");
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  s.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);
          String xmlpacket = "";
          String pom;

          pom = in.readLine();
          //while ((pom = in.readLine()) != null) {
              xmlpacket += pom;
              xmlpacket += "\n";
          //}
          int commaPos = xmlpacket.indexOf(',');
          int newlinePos = xmlpacket.indexOf('\n');
          String login = xmlpacket.substring(0, commaPos);
          String passwd = xmlpacket.substring(commaPos + 1, newlinePos);                        

          boolean clientExists = false;
          for (User us : users) {
              if (us.isUserNameAndPasswordRight(login, passwd)) {
                  out.println("user is connected");
                  clientExists = true;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (!clientExists)
              out.println("bad login");
          out.close();
          in.close();
          s.close();
      }
  } catch (java.io.IOException exp) {
      System.out.println("chyba u socketu!");
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Try taking away the `out.close()` and see what happens.  I believe that closing the `OutputStream` also closes the related socket.  You don't want to do that until you've read the response.

**Update**:  just to be clear, I mean taking away (or moving to the end) the `out.close()` in the client, not the server.

Comment: This is what think too but when I add it to the end then client is not responding and server don´t get message with login and password.

Comment: @Bibo - if you have done some debugging than you should tell us about it!  If you do not give us all the information you have, we are just wasting our time.

Comment: @MartinJames I know the feeling, usually someone gets there before me :-)

Comment: @MartinJames I am sorry, I tried more changes in my code and when I write ´out.close´ to end then I have problem with reading on server side in while. It just reads string for last but one and then it ends and don´t continue in code.

Answer (score 2):

'out.print(name + "," + pass);'  does not seem to issue a line terminator and so the 'readLine()' in your client will not return.  Try 'println' and get rid of the close bodge.

Comment: Still can´t get through while. I read all data with that println but not continue in code.

Comment: It looks like in.ReadLine() is still waiting for more lines to read or I don´t know why in debbuger I am in while and then when It should goes to next line of code but green line in debbuger miss (I use eclipse) and gui in client is not responding.

Comment: The server has the same issue: 'out.print("user is connected");' - no terminator tx.